# Images won't center using tailwind in component

Tags: reactjs, image, grid, components, tailwind-css

I'm trying to align my text with my images for the grid that I've created but for what ever reason it won't line up.

Skills.jsx

```
<div className='grid grid-cols-3 gap-0 mt-10 m-auto '>
            {images.map((image) => (
                <div key={image.id} className='h-full w-full'>
                    <img src={image.img} alt={image.name} className='w-4/12 h-4/12  my-5 border-4 border-black justify-center items-center' />
                    <h2 className='text-center'>{image.name}</h2>
                </div>
            ))}
        </div>
```

[Grid of Images](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fTo5b.png)

I'm trying to make a nice presentlable look for my list of skills. To be honest if anyone has a better recommendation for going about doing this component, I'd take that too. Been stuck on coming up with something good for a while.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hello you can align it vertically by using this

```
<div class='grid grid-cols-3 gap-0 mt-10 m-auto'>
<div class='h-full w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
    <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/601/PNG/256/html_5_icon-icons.com_55763.png" alt="HTML icon" class='w-4/12 h-4/12 my-5 border-4 border-black justify-center items-center' />
    <h2 class='text-center'>HTML</h2>
</div>
 <div class='h-full w-full flex flex-col items-center justify-center'>
    <img src="https://cdn.icon-icons.com/icons2/601/PNG/256/html_5_icon-icons.com_55763.png" alt="HTML icon" class='w-4/12 h-4/12 my-5 border-4 border-black justify-center items-center' />
    <h2 class='text-center'>HTML</h2>
</div>
```